# i uploaded Magmi, now what?

Tags: magmi

As per this instruction page (these apparently are the "complete" installation instructions)

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Installing_Magmi#Directory_permissions_.2F_Magmi_upgrade

I have uploaded Magmi to my server, now what?

I can't go to any pages within it
it isn't in my magento admin area

how am I supposed to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed version 0.7.22 or better as there are numerous security improvements.

Here is a quick list of steps to get up and running:

1. Go to `http://yourstore.com/magmi/web/magmi.php`
2. Enter `magmi` as both the user name and password in the HTTPAuth dialog for your first login
3. Fill in your Magento admin credentials and paths and save the settings
4. Perform any other desired configuration
5. Logout (destroy cookies if needed) and login with your admin credentials

Comment: thank you for this, i am getting the following error   Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /magmi/web/magmi.php on this server.          i confirmed that permissions are 705, ran this on the folder chmod -R 705 magmi

Comment: Your host may have blocked Magmi (I've seen this happen on Nexcess). Try renaming the `magmi` directory to something like `importer` and see what happens.

Comment: that was it, thank you. So i finally got the the Magmi page, it had error "No Profile saved yet, Run disabled!!" i entered my database credentials and saved. There it prompted the htpassword again. Magmi , Magmi no longer work, i tried my db user and pass as a test as well, no luck.  Now I can't even go to any pages within Magmi, I get 404 errors or the htpassword box..

Comment: If you followed step 3, you should be able to login with your Magento admin credentials.

Comment: I figured that out, Tx Joseph